# [SOLVED]how to get graphic driver version in linux

Tags: linux, drivers

I want to check the exactly version of graphic driver in linux.
note, not the device info in "lspci".

I want to get the driver version. for example, I install xf86-video-vesa and xf86-video-ati, how to check which one is loaded?

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check in X log `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`
look for `LoadModule: xxxx` lines